# Compatibility of ATI Radeon HD 2400 XT & VisionTek Radeon x1550

Tags: video, drivers, amd-radeon, lag

I recently added another video card to my workstation - VisionTek Radeon x1550 in addition to ATI Radeon HD 2400 XT that I already had. I was wondering if there is any definitive way to know if there could be any compatibility issues with them?

The reason I am asking is that the video on the monitors connected to x1550 is very choppy & lags a lot. I tried switching monitors but same result.

Alternatively is it that only x1550 is to blame. I have installed latest drivers for both of them. So that should not be an issue.

EDIT: 
Radeon HD 2400 XT is installed on PCIe slot & Radeon x1550 is installed on PCI slot. 1 PCIe x1 expansion slot is available.

Comment: How are they installed in the computer? PCI-E slots? PCI?  How many other expansion cards are there?

Comment: Radeon HD 2400 XT is installed on PCIe slot & Radeon x1550 is installed on PCI slot. 1 PCIe x1 expansion slot is available.

Answer (score 2):

multi-monitor setups involving PCI graphics cards are often laggy and choppy, don't expect much from that regarding performance. the PCI bus is a real bottleneck, it works alright but it is not an ideal solution.

for about half the price of the Radeon x1550 you'll get a [Radeon HD 4350](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16814131143) PCIe card with 512 MB RAM and 2 separate display controllers (and much better dual monitor experience).

Comment: cool. since I have only 1 PCI-e x16 which is already occupied I was thinking of this http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16814161280 I can mount it on the PCI-e x1 slot that I had empty. Will this have better performance than the suggestion you provided?

Comment: no, it's pretty much the same card just a different connector and 80 dollar dearer (and noisier because it has a fan). you might as well replace your HD 2400 with that 35 dollar HD4350 (thought i have seen this card for 29.99 at tigerdirect) and drive both monitors on the one card. i'm using the same card with 2x 1920x1200 HDMI & DVI, works just fine.

Comment: @Molly the thing is I have to connect 3 monitors. I forgot to mention this in the question.

Comment: right, then go ahead and get that PCIe x1 card ... but still, $115 is a pretty steep price.